# Unable to evaluate dense tensor obtained from a complex sparse tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am unable to evaluate/print/run a dense tensor obtained from a complex sparse tensor in tensorflow library. I am currently using build #234 of tensorflow in macosx (cpu only).

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]], values=[1.0+2j, 2.0], shape=[3, 4, 2])

b = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(a, default_value=0.0)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(b)
```

returns the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'SparseToDense' with these attrs. Registered kernels:
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]

 [[Node: SparseToDense_3 = SparseToDense[T=DT_COMPLEX128, Tindices=DT_INT64, validate_indices=true](SparseTensor_2/indices, SparseTensor_2/shape, SparseTensor_2/values, SparseToDense_3/default_value)]]
```

I also tried:

```
br = tf.real(b)

sess.run(br)
```

However, this gives the same error as above.

Note, however, that the following works fine:

```
x = tf.ones((3,3), dtype=tf.complex128)

sess.run(x)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense does not support complex number yet. I have tried loss the +2j component, and it worked. I think the error dump was trying to tell you that sparse_tensor_to_dense don't support complex type, and list the type it support.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought too. Would it be incredibly difficult to include complex data type on our own? may be by modifying the source code?